# Are there any standards for interpreting PHAdjustmentData?

Tags: ios, photosframework

I'm trying to build a photo editing extension in iOS.  I understand the pipeline of how the existing edits to a photo can be interpreted by the app, but from what I've read there isn't much built on how to interpret the PHAdjustmentData.

For instance, it comes with a formatIdentifier, formatVersion, and an arbitrary data property.  I understand that the data property can be interpreted as a serialized object, but are there any standards that can be used to identify common filters?  Or what about third party filters?  Perhaps some of these are system defined filters that must be queried for and use the same settings to reproduce the history of the image.

For example, if I edit one photo before calling my extension, I'll get the `canHandle(_ adjustMentData:) -> Bool` message.  Printing out that object shows the following.

```
(lldb) po adjustmentData
<PHAdjustmentData: 0x600000055390> identifier=com.apple.photo version=1.2 data=0x6000001a8b20 (204)
```

How does one go about interpreting this?  Clearly the iOS Photos app is the identifier, but the NSData itself could be anything.  I'm sure it could be a dictionary of CIFilter property settings or anything else.

Are there any standards developing to concretely identify this historical data?

Comment: As far as I can see the adjustment data is not really meant to be cross-app compatible. Every vendor can basically define their own data without restrictions or standards. However, in this case, have you tried to treat the data as serialized plist and checked if there's some useful information in it? Would be interesting...

Comment: Yes it's clear that the intention is not to couple into any specific vendor.  I was just thinking that regardless there may still be standard of transform/filter adjustment settings to support interoperability across photo editor extensions.

Answer (score 0):

"No". There is no standard, and furthermore, when you claim you `canHandleAdjustmentData` the framework will pass you an image without the latest edits. So if you do not understand *all* the changes there will be data loss.